# The distribution with the lowest possible variance.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, calculus-of-variations

Let $\phi$ be the family consisting of all random variables $X$ such that $P(X\in [0,1])=1$, $EX=\frac{1}{5}$, $P(X\leq\frac{3}{10})=\frac{1}{2}$. Calculate $\inf \{\rm{Var}(X):X \in \phi\}.$

Could you please give a hint? I have no idea how to start.

Comment: Conjecture: The infimum is $\frac1{100}$, obtained with $P\left(X=\frac1{10}-x\right)=P\left(X=\frac3{10}+x\right)=\frac12$ for $x>0$, $x\to0$.

Comment: I agree with you Did, and as far as I know $\frac{1}{100}$ is the right answer, however I have no idea how to prove this.

Answer (score 2):

A sketch of a proof of Did's conjecture in a comment:

The contribution from $(\frac3{10},1]$ to the variance must be at least $\frac12(\frac3{10}-\frac15)^2=\frac12\cdot\frac1{100}$. If the probability in $[0,\frac3{10}]$ is concentrated in a Dirac mass, it also contributes at least $\frac12(\frac1{10}-\frac15)^2=\frac12\cdot\frac1{100}$, and otherwise even more. I don't know the name of the theorem used in that last statement, but it's analogous to the [Huygens–Steiner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallel_axis_theorem) for moments of inertia.

Comment: Yes. But I am not sure you need any fancy theorems. Half the distribution is at least 0.1 from the mean. You minimise variance by placing it all exactly 0.1 from the mean. Then the contibution from the other half is minimised by placing it 0.1 away on the opposite side.

Comment: @almagest: If it's obvious to you without a theorem that you minimize the variance by putting it all in one place, then good for you -- it wasn't obvious to me before I learned that theorem.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments. Is there any similar reasonings for $\sup\{\rm{Var}\}$? Here the appropriate distiribution is $\frac{1}{2}\delta_{0}+\frac{4}{7}\delta_{\frac{3}{10}}+\frac{1}{14}\delta_{1}$. Why we obtain such point masses and why there are three point masses? (I've got the answer by considering the graph of distribution function).

Comment: @Almostsure: If there were any probability in the interior of the intervals, we could spread it out to increase the variance. If there were non-zero probability on both sides of $\frac3{10}$, we could move it outward on both sides. Thus the limiting distribution has at most three point masses: one at $0$, one at $1$ and one either at ${\frac3{10}}^+$ or ${\frac3{10}}^-$. Having $\frac12$ at $1$ would give the wrong expectation, so we must have $\frac12$ at $0$. Then requiring the expectation to be $\frac15$ determines the weights, but the weight at ${\frac3{10}}^+$ is $\frac37$, not $\frac47$.

Comment: @joriki Use mass. (1) place all mass to rt of 0.3 at 0.3; (2) no mass between 0.2 and 0.3; (3) cm of remaining mass must be at 0.1; (4) variance is higher if you smear it instead of placing all at 0.1. Last step uses well known Moment of Inertia result.

Comment: Maybe that MI result is called the H-S theorem, but the proof is trivial.

Comment: @almagest: I don't understand what you're trying to say. Your comment seems to be a slight variant of the proof I sketched in my answer. About the theorem, I never said that it's a deep theorem or hard to prove, just that there's a theorem for it and its content (not its proof) isn't obvious to me. Perhaps you could clarify what your comments are meant to show.